# How connect prodaction postgersql server to project on locall?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, cloud, devops, gateway

I have running postgresql server on google cloud unbutu machine outside of docker container on  34.159.XX.XX ip. And also django project in docker container. I started django with `docker-compose`, but cannot connect postgres server. I thinck problem is i need some proxy gateways.
error is like :

```
 error: connection to server at "34.159.XX.XX", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have corrected `pg_hba.conf` with this:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and `listen_addresses = '*'`  but i still cant access psql server

Comment: 1) Not clear to me where you are running the Django app: a) On the cloud Ubuntu machine? b) On a machine remote to the Postgres server? 2) What are the connection parameters you are using? 3) What are the error messages you are getting? **Add information as text update to question text**.

Comment: I build services for backend, frontend and nginx in docker and running them, and also have have active postgres server on same machine, but can not connect backend to the database; error is something like:
```
error: connection to server at "34.159.204.45", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

```
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) Reread my comment in particular where to put  the answers to questions. Hint, not in the comments. 2) At same time define backend and frontend. 3) Also what does *...active postgres server on same machine` mean? Inside docker or outside?

Comment: I have modified my question, postgres it is autside of docker container @AdrianKlaver

Comment: There is a firewall blocking your access.  Probably Google's.  Configure you GCP instance to allow connections from your host.